# copying data to an array in javascript d3.js and then drawing a scatterplot

Tags: javascript, arrays, graph, d3.js

Im new to javascript and d3.js and trying to understand scatter plots.
I used this code, works fine:

```
//Get the data
d3.tsv("graphdata.tsv", function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.open = +d.open;
        });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.close; })]);

// draw the scatterplot
        svg.selectAll("dot")                                    
            .data(data)                                         
        .enter().append("circle")                               
            .attr("r", 8)                                     
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date); })     
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.close); })    
            .style("fill", color(9));
```

But when I copy the contents of "data" to "anArray", and then try to plot the data in anArray, I get an empty graph.

```
//Get the data
d3.tsv("graphdata.tsv", function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.open = +d.open;
        });

var anArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++)
       anArray.push(data[i]);

x.domain(d3.extent(anArray, function (d) { return anArray.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(anArray, function (d) { return anArray.close; })]);

// draw the scatterplot
        svg.selectAll("dot")                                    
            .data(anArray)                                          
        .enter().append("circle")                               
            .attr("r", 8)                                     
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(anArray.date); })       
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(anArray.close); })  
            .style("fill", color(9));
```

I want to know why does this happen? And if I need to do such a thing, is there a another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

been a while since I used d3, but I think the problem is here:

`x.domain(d3.extent(anArray, function (d) { return anArray.date; }));`

`y.domain([0, d3.max(anArray, function (d) { return anArray.close; })]);`

and

`.attr("cx", function (d) { return x(anArray.date); })`

`.attr("cy", function (d) { return y(anArray.close); })`

you're asking it to return `anArray.date` and `anArray.close` when it should be `d.date` and `d.close`.

try changing this to:

`x.domain(d3.extent(anArray, function (d) { return d.date; }));`

and

`.attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date); })`